# ffi_prep_closure(): bad user_data (it seems that the version of the libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' seen at compile-time)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, traceback, libffi

I am running few python scripts on my raspberry pi4 running  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1034-raspi aarch64)..But today all scripts stopped working and I'm getting this exception in all of them..

```
ffi_prep_closure(): bad user_data (it seems that the version of the libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' file seen at compile-time)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually interested in the root cause of this but you can probably fix your issue by pinning the version of `cffi` to `<=1.15.0`.

A new version of `cffi` was published on 30 June which is, I presume, why you started seeing errors around that time.

I'm seeing the same error messages on Ubuntu 20.04 but not on Arch Linux.